# Simple edge loop won't Grid Fill

Tags: mesh, vertices

This edge loop (the roof of the car I'm trying to create) consists of 34 vertices on each long side, and 8 vertices on each short side. Together with the 4 corner vertices that makes 88 vertices in total. I'd say the **perfect** set-up for a **Grid Fill** ... except that it does not work (see error at top of screen). I checked for double vertices, there are none. I checked if the loop is water tight, by using ctrl+RMB select, and that's all ok. So what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you provide only the vertices on both short edges as initial selection for the command?

Comment: If you extrude inwards and grid fill it should work. You need supporting outside topology to determine the direction of the fill.

Comment: The problem has been solved, but don't know how. Had redrawn the edge loop, and afterwards it workded. thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by the Blender manual's section about the **[Grid fill](https://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill)** command:

> Grid Fill uses a **pair** of connected edge-loops to fill in a grid that
>   follows the surrounding geometry.

[image]

Despite this, using the vertices indices and the picking order, the operator is capable to guess the user intention even if he defines the whole boundary, but it still needs to guess the right **offset**'s and **span**'s values because you are not providing edgeloops but only some vertices and it has to guess which gruops of them belong to an edgeloop.

[image]

See in this sequence how the operator behaves differently on same geometry simply by picking another vertex to complete the selection.

[image]